# Can I confirm that a variable is never defined by inspecting compiler/linker output?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, extern

I have a C++ project with a variable that appears to be defined/declared as `extern` everywhere; the actual definition does not seem to exist, yet the project/solution builds and runs.

Is it possible for me to confirm that this variable really isn't defined anywhere by inspecting build outputs (e.g. .lib files, .exe files, etc)? Is there a more practical way of identifying variables that are defined everywhere as `extern`, e.g. some compiler strictness setting?

I've checked this discussion for subtleties of `extern`:
[Using the 'extern' keyword properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867431/using-the-extern-keyword-properly)

It appears that all of the declarations in my solution do **not** include initializers, thus all of the declarations really are declarations and not definitions.

My project/solution is built with Visual Studio 2019 (v142).

The reason I'm wondering about this, is that I was refactoring some code and this variable was marked as undefined. When I searched for the location of the definition, I couldn't find it. At that point, I realized that it was 'extern' everywhere and I didn't understand how it was working.

The variable declarations look like this:

```
extern VariableType * variableName ;
```

There are no other special keywords or declspec annotations.

The variable is used like this:

```
extern ThisType * thisVar;

if(thisVar->flag)
{
 //Do something
}
```

Per @Michael Dorgan's suggestion, I've tried inspecting the .map file. In the .map file, it appears that the variable is first declared as extern, and in the next occurrence it's used as a function parameter. So I am not sure how to proceed with the .map file.

---

Edit: For future readers, I ended up creating a tags file as suggested in the link. This worked fine using the universal-ctags pre-built binary for Windows. The commands I used were:

```
ctags.exe -R  
readtags.exe variableName
```

This printed out the location where the variable was actually defined; it was not `extern` everywhere, I had missed it in one location. The Visual Studio feature 'Go To Definition' does not seem to be working on this variable; I had to right-click and choose 'Find all References', which showed the correct location.

Comment: extern tells the compiler "Trust me even though you cannot see this symbol, the linker will fix it up."  If the compiled code references the variables and the linker cannot resolve them, then you will get a linker error and know it is missing.  If you really want to know what is defined and where, generate a map file.  It will show where everything is.

Comment: If the declaration includes compiler-specific COMDAT specifiers -  such as MSVC's __declspec(selectany) then a definition will be generated if none is provided. It is very common with COMDAT variables to not actually explicitly provide a definition because that would have to go in a translation unit somewhere and many COMDAT uses are in libraries and thus the library user would have to make additional modifications for things that really should be library internals.

Comment: Are you sure the variable is actually *used*?  If the variable is merely declared but not actually used in any code, no references would be generated and you wouldn't get any errors.

Comment: But you're asking for compiler-specific solutions without telling what compiler you're using.

Comment: Why do you need to confirm this? Are you running into an error linking, or do you just not like the variable or something?

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, the variable is used. The compiler is the Visual Studio 2019 C++ compiler; the projects are all set to Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2019 (v142). I will add that detail to the description.

Comment: @Chipster I want to confirm this because I'm refactoring to clean things up, and moving  a file resulting in this variable being undefined. I realized that I didn't know where it was originally declared when I searched for it and it appeared as 'extern' everywhere.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir none of the declarations have anything beyond `extern VariableType * variableName ;`

Comment: @MichaelDorgan sounds like map file is what I was looking for, I will try that.

Comment: @afarley Are you lucky enough to have code previous code versions to look at? Because that might be your best bet. Unfortunately C++ itself doesn't have a lot of options to do this that I'm aware. I'm also not the biggest expert on these types of things, so there may be something I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Chipster as in a git commit history? I do have that, but I was hoping for a more white-box method of inspecting variable locations rather than just trying to identify the particular commit that created this situation. I'm more interested in what's going on right now than the history of the code-base.

Comment: @afarley Yeah, I was thinking something like git. C++ just doesn't really do that. Your IDE might have something, but that's about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216990/discussion-between-afarley-and-chipster).